# Failed to build gem native extension for rubinius-melbourne

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, rubinius

i'm trying to install rubinius 2.2.5 on centos 6.5 (64 bits),I already installed ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux] when I write in the console  `bundle install`I get this error

```
[root@localhost rubinius-2.2.5]# bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.1.1
Using daedalus-core 0.0.3
Using gems 0.8.3
Using redcard 1.1.0
Using rubinius-ast 2.0.11
Using rubinius-bridge 1.0.3
Using rubinius-compiler 2.0.4
Using rubinius-toolset 0.1.1

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling encoding_compat.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling melbourne.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling node_types.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling visitor.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling var_table.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
generating parser grammar.y
make: bison: Command not found
make: *** [grammar.cpp] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rubinius-melbourne-2.0.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/rubinius-melbourne-2.0.1.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rubinius-melbourne (2.0.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rubinius-melbourne -v '2.0.1.0'` succeeds before bundling. 
[root@localhost rubinius-2.2.5]# gem install rubinius-melbourne -v '2.0.1.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rubinius-melbourne:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling encoding_compat.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling melbourne.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling node_types.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling visitor.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling var_table.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
generating parser grammar.y
make: bison: Command not found
make: *** [grammar.cpp] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rubinius-melbourne-2.0.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/rubinius-melbourne-2.0.1.0/gem_make.out
[root@localhost rubinius-2.2.5]# gem install rubinius-melbourne
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rubinius-melbourne:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling encoding_compat.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling melbourne.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling node_types.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling visitor.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling var_table.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
generating parser grammar.y
make: bison: Command not found
make: *** [grammar.cpp] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rubinius-melbourne-2.0.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/rubinius-melbourne-2.0.1.0/gem_make.out
[root@localhost rubinius-2.2.5]# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.4)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.6.0.rc)
daedalus-core (0.0.3)
gems (0.8.3)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.3)
rake (10.1.1, 10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
redcard (1.1.0)
rubinius-ast (2.0.11)
rubinius-bridge (1.0.3)
rubinius-compiler (2.0.4)
rubinius-toolset (0.1.1)
rubygems-update (2.2.2)
test-unit (2.1.1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you don't have 'bison' installed.

Please see requirements for 'rubinius' http://rubini.us/doc/en/getting-started/requirements/

In centos you need to following libraries

- ruby-devel
- readline-devel
- zlib-devel
- openssl-devel